# Space station of beheaded king

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Funny actor Lemmon (leaving out Matthau, at first) showing part of 1 down (5,5)
>   6. Space station of beheaded king (3)
>   9. Sumerian city inside Brazilian city? That's perfectly normal (7)
>   10. Paul follows a hundred chat groups (7)
>   11. A must-see in 1 across: some harmonicas in orchestra (6)
>   13. Part of Canada ignored a head of state of 1 down (6)
>   16. Remote selling of skiing technique by alien with gin cocktail (13)
>   19. Armenia rented out sea bordered by 1 down (13)
>   22. Roll in African priest (needing no introduction) to show theological concept (6)
>   24. Warden and resistance leader meeting with hatred (6)
>   28. A piece of tumor Ceauceșcu concealed (7)
>   29. One hosted by vacant free state, smaller than 1 down (7)
>   31/14d. Elements of syntax have nothing leading to 1 down, for one (3,5)
>   32. Make up a language in a French competition hosted by 1 down (7,3)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Country's team on a cool part (6)
>   2. *Rolling Stone* showing symbols of musical sounds (5)
>   3. Make a mistake in terror (3)
>   4. Competent comeuppance of 19 across island (4)
>   5. Need for a unit of energy briefly brought up (4)
>   6. Possibly all mine in thousands of years (9)
>   7. Adjusts and tastes erroneous part from the south (6)
>   8. A woman retreating to Dead Sea? (4)
>   12. Lesions on the skin resulting from tainted Evian (5)
>   14. *(See 31 across)*
>   15. Avoid women's clothing (5)
>   17. Bringer of death for the last member of police – copper eaten by horrible T-Rex next to retired Chinese leader (9)
>   18. Country guitarist on Gaffney piece (5)
>   20. Top university under siege, undermining most entrances (6)
>   21. Authority having lost his country, neighbouring 1 down (6)
>   23. Links time that is short, at first (4)
>   25. Popular science magazine covering Louis's reptile (5)
>   26. Unlimited nerve cell currency of 1 down (4)
>   27. Cell block never injures human hearts (4)
>   30. Chess champion in Italy (3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Filled crossword (and some comments)

> [image]

Thanks to @LannyStrack for a lot of help with the last few clues and explanations.

The big break was to solve 1 down, as that made a lot of the other clues doable/easy by association. But it took me a while to get it. The first clue I solved was 15 down, although I stupidly wrote it in the 18 down position at first - that's why the intersection of 18 down and 19 across looks a bit strange. 12 down taught me a new word.

### Clue explanations

**Across**

1. Funny actor Lemmon (leaving out Matthau, at first) showing part of 1 down (5,5)

> MONTE CARLO (def "part of 1 down", anagram of "actor Lemmon" minus M)

6. Space station of beheaded king (3)

> MIR (def "space station", EMIR minus first letter)

9. Sumerian city inside Brazilian city? That's perfectly normal (7)

> NATURAL (def "perfectly normal", UR inside NATAL)

10. Paul follows a hundred chat groups (7)

> CIRCLES (def "groups", C plus IRC plus LES [apparently Les Paul is some kind of famous person?]). Thanks @LannyStrack!

11. A must-see in 1 across: some harmonicas in orchestra (6)

> CASINO (def "must-see in [Monaco]", found in "harmoniCAS IN Orchestra")

13. Part of Canada ignored a head of state of 1 down (6)

> ALBERTA (def "head of state of [Monaco]", ALBERTA minus A)

16. Remote selling of skiing technique by alien with gin cocktail (13)

> TELEMARKETING (def "remote selling" - TELEMARK plus ET plus anagram of "gin")

19. Armenia rented out sea bordered by 1 down (13)

> MEDITERRANEAN (def "sea bordered by 1 down", anagram of "Armenia rented")

22. Roll in African priest (needing no introduction) to show theological concept (6)

> UBUNTU (def "theological concept", BUN in TUTU minus first letter)

24. Warden and resistance leader meeting with hatred (6)

> RANGER (def "warden", first letter of Resistance plus ANGER). Thanks @LannyStrack!

28. A piece of tumor Ceauceșcu concealed (7)

> MORCEAU (def "piece", found in "tuMOR CEAUcescu")

29. One hosted by vacant free state, smaller than 1 down (7)

> VATICAN (def "state smaller than [Monaco]", I in anagram of VACANT)

31/14d. Elements of syntax have nothing leading to 1 down, for one (3,5)

> TAX HAVEN (def "[Monaco], for one", found in "synTAX HAVE Nothing")

32. Make up a language in a French competition hosted by 1 down (7,3)

> FORMULA ONE (def "competition hosted by [Monaco]", "make up" = FORM plus LAO language inside UNE). Thanks @ChrisCudmore!

**Down**

1. Country's team on a cool part (6)

> MONACO (def "country", found in "teaM ON A COol")

2. Rolling Stone showing symbols of musical sounds (5)

> NOTES (def "symbols of musical sounds", anagram of "stone")

3. Make a mistake in terror (3)

> ERR (def "make a mistake", found in "tERRor")

4. Competent comeuppance of 19 across island (4)

> ABLE (def "competent", ELBA backwards). Thanks @WeatherVane!

5. Need for a unit of energy briefly brought up (4)

> LACK (def "need for", KCAL backwards)

6. Possibly all mine in thousands of years (9)

> MILLENNIA (def "thousands of years", anagram of "all mine in")

7. Adjusts and tastes erroneous part from the south (6)

> RESETS (def "adjusts", found backwards in "taSTES ERroneous")

8. A woman retreating to Dead Sea? (4)

> ARAL (def "dead sea", LARA backwards). Thanks @LannyStrack!

12. Lesions on the skin resulting from tainted Evian (5)

> NAEVI (def "lesions on the skin", anagram of "Evian")

14. (See 31 across)
15. Avoid women's clothing (5)

> SKIRT (ddef)

17. Bringer of death for the last member of police – copper eaten by horrible T-Rex next to retired Chinese leader (9)

> EXECUTRIX (def "bringer of death" - last letter of policE plus CU inside anagram of TREX plus XI backwards)

18. Country guitarist on Gaffney piece (5)

> TONGA (def "country", found in "guitarisT ON GAffney")

20. Top university under siege, undermining most entrances (6)

> SUMMIT (def "top", first letters of Siege Undermining Most plus MIT)

21. Authority having lost his country, neighbouring 1 down (6)

> FRANCE (def "country neighbouring [Monaco]", FRANCHISE minus HIS)

23. Links time that is short, at first (4)

> TIES (def "links", T plus IE plus first letter of Short). Thanks @LannyStrack!

25. Popular science magazine covering Louis's reptile (5)

> GECKO (def "reptile", GEO covering CK [apparently Louis CK is some kind of famous person?]). Thanks @LannyStrack!

26. Unlimited nerve cell currency of 1 down (4)

> EURO (def "currency of [Monaco]", NEURON minus first and last letters)

27. Cell block never injures human hearts (4)

> OVUM (def "cell", middle letters of "blOck neVer injUres huMan")

30. Chess champion in Italy (3)

> TAL (def "chess champion", found in "iTALy")

Comment: 4 down is rot13(noyr, sebz Ryon).

Comment: 24a enatre 'e'(rfvfgnapr) + 'natre'  
23d gvrf 'g'(vzr) + 'v.r.' + 'f'(ubeg)  
25d trpxb 'TRB' nebhaq (Ybhvf) 'PX'

Comment: How do I put a carriage return / newline in a comment?

Comment: @LannyStrack Thanks! In 24A the "and" was confusing me into trying to make the join in the wrong place. In 25D, why CK = Louis??? 23D - wow, nice one! I also got 22A now. And you can't put a carriage return in a comment.

Comment: Well, unless you employ some Latex trickery $${}$$ like this.

Comment: 10a pvepyrf   'p' + 'VEP' + Yrf (Cnhy)

Comment: Louis CK is an American stand-up comedian.

Comment: 8d neny ('ynen' onpxjneqf) Neny Frn ab ybatre rkvfgf, fb vf "qrnq"

Comment: 22a hohagh  (G)'hgh' nebhaq 'oha'

Comment: 20d fhzzvg   'f'(vrtr) 'h'(aqrezvavat) 'z'(bfg) + ZVG (Znff. Vafg. bs Grpu.)

Comment: 16a 'gryrznex' (glcr bs fxvvat) + 'RG' + 'tva' fpenzoyrq

Comment: @LannyStrack 10A: thanks! another one I wouldn't have got since it involves celebrities. 8D: aww, that sea :-( I already got 22A in my previous edit, and 20D independently :-)

Comment: @LannyStrack Oh wow. I only knew Telemark as a region of Norway!

Comment: 17d (cbyvp)'r' + 'gerk' whzoyrq nebhaq 'ph' + 'Kv' onpxjneqf

Comment: 21d 'senapuvfr' - 'uvf'

Comment: Les Paul was an early pioneer of the electric guitar. Very influential.

Comment: I can't quite get 32a. V guvax 'znxr' vf 'SBEZ', 'hc' vf 'H', naq 'n Serapu' vf 'YR'.

Comment: 32a: I think rot13(SBEZHYN vf pnzr sebz SBEZHYNGR, hc (gb) N).

Comment: @LannyStrack Wow, putting "copper" next to "police" had me so totally fooled that I didn't even think of the other meaning! Nice one.

Comment: I think I've got 32a, but it won't make everybody happy. 'ynathntr' = B.A. (Byq Abefr; frra va qvpgvbanevrf va jbeq rglzbybtl rkcynangvbaf)
Gurersber, znxr -> 'SBEZ', hc -> 'H', n ynathntr -> 'NBA'  va 'n Serapu' -> 'YR'

Comment: Nah, I think it's rot13(gur jbeq "znxr hc" vf n abha urer. "Purzvpny Znxr Hc" = "Purzvpny Sbezhyn")

Comment: All correct except the explanation for 32a :) Hint: "French" is not part of the def.

Comment: @jafe Are any of the attempts in comments above correct? I'll happily edit in someone else's explanation, but none of them has me convinced yet.

Comment: No, nobody's guessed the correct formulation (pun not intended). Also, note that "le" is the French equivalent of "the", not "a".

Comment: @jafe Yeah I knew that, hence why that attempt for 32a didn't convince me ;-)

Comment: 32: Rot13(Znxr hc = SBEZ Ynathntr = YNB N Serapu = HAR -- SBEZ+H(YNB)AR)

Comment: @jafe Finally complete thanks to Chris Cudmore. Quite a few really devilish clues (not in the printer's sense either) in there!